# how to read and write to the same file using swift with Xcode developing an iOS App

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, struct

I am entering the Swift/Xcode-World coming from the Java-World and are struggling with File -path and -access. My App (iOS) needs to open a number of json-Files, encodes them to structs, and on every change which occurs - the user edits data - the same structs should be saved again as the same json files.

This instant structs/json-synchronization is essential to not loose data in case of a crashed App or iPad.

Everything works as it should - but the simulator saves the files at a different location as the input files, although the path looks to same (to me at least..). I know I should use observable classes instead of @state structs, but the model is rather complex and it would be a pain in the a. to convert the structs to classes. Anyway I guess this is not causing my file problem.

This is where I load the json`s:

```
func load_fuelHeader (_ filename: String) ->  fuelheader{
let data: Data

guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
}

do {
    data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
} catch {
    fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    return try decoder.decode(fuelheader.self, from: data)
} catch {
    fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(fuelheader.self):\n\(error)")
}
```

}

This is the call to this func:

```
@State var FuelData=load_fuelHeader ("FuelHeader.json")
```

This is how I save the structs back to json`s:

```
    func saveData(){

    var jsonString:String?
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        do{
            let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(myFuelData)
            jsonString=String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch {
            print (error)
    }

    guard let SaveFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "FuelHeader.json", withExtension: nil) else { fatalError("Couldn't find \("FuelHeader.json") in main bundle.") }

    do {
        try jsonString?.write(to: SaveFile, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

During debugging the loaded file is

```
file:///Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BBEDCD2E-05E0-4261-A08F-D214D101980F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8C92D2FB-344F-4516-AA22-32F54EE1386C/ofp.app/FuelHeader.json
```

while the saved file is the same, as it should be:

file:///Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BBEDCD2E-05E0-4261-A08F-D214D101980F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8C92D2FB-344F-4516-AA22-32F54EE1386C/ofp.app/FuelHeader.json

I checked the file, it is correct, it contains the changed data.The Problem is, the app does not load the above file, instead it loads the one within the xcode-project folder:

```
/Users/.../Documents/swift-projects/ofp/ofp/ressources/FuelHeader.json
```

for sure I missed some basics here, but I can`t find a solution yet.

Comment: You cannot write into the application bundle. For obvious reasons it’s read-only. You have to copy the file into the documents folder of the app and modify it there.

Comment: Have you considered using a database like SQLite? That seems to be much better suited than doing the (rather slow) JSON serialization/deserialisation dance whenever something changes.

Comment: @vadian thanks for your input. Thing is, once I open the saved (changed) json inside the temp folder of the simulator, it is indeed correctly changed. But a re-load of the json during the same debugger session does not load the same file, it loads the one within the swift-projects folder, which is used within Xcode. By the time I start the next Xcode run or test session, all changes are gone.

Comment: Meanwhile I found out that everything works fine once I stop the Xcode debugging session and run the App on the simulator on its own. It reads and writes from and to the same file. If I start the simulator from Xcode, it again loads not the file from the bundle, but from the Xcode project folder. How can one change this to be able to debug?